# rails: can't mass assign to these protected attributes while trying to set STI type during create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance

I have just started out learning rails and ruby, so please bear with me if this is too dumb.

There are several different AppModule types in my app, which have different behavior but similar data, so I save them using single table inheritance.

However when trying allow the user to explicitly select which type they want in `app_modules/new.html.erb` I get the warning `WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: type`. Here is the relevant code:

```
<% form_for(@app_module) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :type %><br />
    <%= f.select( :type, options_from_collection_for_select(AppModule.subclasses().map{ |c| c.name}, 'to_s', 'to_s')) %>
    </p>

  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
 <% end %>
```

I have tried explicity setting `attr_accessible :type` in the model file but it didn't work

I am using rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't ever have to set the type attribute manually. Use the subclasses you created instead.

```
model = params[:app_module].delete(:type).constantize
model = AppModule unless model.is_a?(AppModule)
@app_module = model.new(params[:app_module])
```

Comment: This is really convenient with STI.

Comment: Of course you'd add a check to ensure only types you specifically allow can be created in this fashion. That code would allow a user to create any class they like within your app and provide it with whatever initialisation parameters they want (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @BrendonMuir Yes that's a good point, you should always sanitize params that execute code like this. I'll add a line for that.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. I know this question is for Rails 2 but in Rails 4 they added the ability to specify :type in the attributes and it does a check that :type is a valid subclass of the superclass: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/89b5b31cc4f8407f648a2447665ef23f9024e8a5

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your base class:

```
  def attributes_protected_by_default
    super - [self.class.inheritance_column]
  end
```

I recommend Adam's method unless you are dealing with a mixed list.

Answer (score 0):

I just need to comment following line in my 'config/application.rb' to solve this issue.

```
# config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```